# How to stop excel copying adjacent formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel seems to be determined to copy the format of an adjacent cell. For instance, when I have a cell that has a green background with a number in it, then when entering a number in an adjacent cell the background also becomes green. This is extremely annoying in many cases and requires me to clear the background.

Is there a way to turn this "Excel thinks for me" feature off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is this feature in Excel to **Turn on or off extended formats and formulas**.

**For Excel 2007:**
**1.** Click on `Office Button` [image] at the top left of the screen.
**2.** At the bottom, you will see the `Excel Options` button. Click it to open Excel Options Window.
**3.** Select `Advanced` from the list on the left side.
**4.** **Uncheck** `Extend data range formats and formulas`.

[image]

**For Older versions of Excel:**

Go to the `Tools`, `Options` and select the `Edit Tab`, then **uncheck** the `Extend list formats and formulas`.

[image]

Comment: I only see 'Add Comment' 'Answer Your Question'.  how do I accept your answer as a solution?

Comment: @FiliepSamyn - You'll have to click tick mark on the top left of my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed a very annoying format behavior. This is still the solution for Excel Office 365 (2020) as well.