# How do I stop excel from auto formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I am adding data to a table, there may be formatting in the line above such as a highlighted cell that I do not want copied when I enter data on the next line, but when I finish typing in a the cell below it then automatically gets the color of the line above it.

I want to turn auto formatting off entirely.  I can set up formatting as I see fit and do not want any shortcuts because in the end they actually make more work.  How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop excel copying adjecent formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/1082009/how-to-stop-excel-copying-adjecent-formatting)

Comment: @joe any luck with the method in the link?